# Upload de arquivos com Vue.js e FilePond

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que faz upload de arquivos usando a biblioteca 'FilePond', que é um gerenciador de arquivos. Ao selecionar o arquivo que sofrerá upload, a biblioteca retorna o blob do arquivo, que é o que está sendo utilizado para fazer o upload via uma API REST.

```
formData.append('image', this.vetorArquivos[i].file)
```

onde this.vetorArquivos[i].file é o blob que está indo para a API. O grande problema é que trabalhando desta forma, o  'filename' deste arquivo se torna 'blob', sendo que o necessário é que vá com o nome do arquivo.

Este blob tem os seguintes atributos:

```
Blob {
    lastModifiedDate: Fri Nov 08 2019 22:35:08 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de 
    Brasília) 
    name: "Clean_Code.pdf"
    size: 4261722
    type: "application/pdf"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [`formData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) aceita 3 argumentos. O nome a passar ao `form`, o valor (neste caso o ficheiro) e por ultimo o nome do ficheiro quando se trata de um Blob.

Ora sendo que podes saber o nome do ficheiro via `.name` o teu código poderia ser assim:

```
const arquivo = this.vetorArquivos[i].file;
formData.append('image', arquivo, arquivo.name)
```